# MacOS zshrc Bad Math Expression operator expected

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to display to a user when their authentication is about to expire when their `.zshrc` is sourced on either MacOS or Linux. When running directly in `zsh` everything appears fine. However when running `source ~/.zshrc` on `MacOS` it throws the error:

```
└─> source ~/.zshrc
check_token:35: bad math expression: operator expected at `23:17:10'
```

It appears to want to perform an operation on the following line:

```
ISO_expiry_date="${expiry_year}/${expiry_month}/${expiry_day}${expiry_time}"
```

The full code snippet it below:

```
check_token() {
  command="auth"

  token -s
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  
    echo "Authetication not present, running $command"
    eval $command
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && [[ $? -ne 130 ]]; then
      check_token
    fi
  fi

  token -s
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    token=`tokenlist | grep string`
    ISO_expiry_date=""

    if [[ `uname` == "Linux" ]]; then
      expiry_date=`echo $token | awk '{print $3}'`
      # Alter from American date format to ISO
      expiry_date_parts=(${(s[/])expiry_date})
      expiry_time=`echo $token | awk '{print $4}'`
      ISO_expiry_date="$expiry_date_parts[3]/$expiry_date_parts[2]/$expiry_date_parts[1] $expiry_time"
    elif [[ `uname` == "Darwin" ]]; then
      expiry_day=`echo $token | awk '{print $6}'`
      printf -v expiry_day "%02d" $expiry_day
      month=`echo $token | awk '{print $5}'`
      expiry_month=`date -j -f "%b" "$month" +"%m"`
      expiry_year=`echo $token | awk '{print $8}'`

      expiry_time=" `echo $token | awk '{print $7}'`"

      ISO_expiry_date="${expiry_year}/${expiry_month}/${expiry_day}${expiry_time}"
    fi

    if [[ $ISO_expiry_date -ne "" ]]; then
      echo "Ticket will expire at $ISO_expiry_date"
    else
      echo "Current ticket: $token"
    fi
  fi
}
```

`tokenlist` displays something similar to the following on Mac:

```
  Issued                Expires               Principal
Sep  1 13:17:14 2022  Sep  1 23:17:10 2022  string
```

zsh version:

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

MacOS version:

```
sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.5.1
BuildVersion:   21G83
```

Comment: `-ne` is an arithmetic operator; you want `!=` for string comparison.

Comment: Add a hashbang, `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`, to the first line of your test script. The times that it appeared to work were likely being run in `sh`, not `zsh` (and the `-ne` comparison probably didn't work, it just didn't report an error).

Comment: `ISO_expiry_date` is just set to a string; no error here. But later on you try to use this string as a number, and this is why you got the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ $ISO_expiry_date -ne "" ]]` does a numeric comparison, which fails because the value of `$ISO_expiry_date` can't be converted to a number. You should instead use either

```
[[ $ISO_expiry_date != "" ]]
```

if you want to compare arbitrary strings, or

```
[[ -n $ISO_expiry_date ]]
```

if you want to specifically check if a string is not empty. In Zsh programming, to check for empty strings, the latter is generally preferred over the former.

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html for more info.